# Vector space over $\mathbb C$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\phi_1,\phi_2\in[0,2\pi):\phi_1\le\phi_2$ and $S=\{z\in\mathbb C:\arg(z)\in[\phi_1,\phi_2]\}$. Check if $(S,+,\cdot,\mathbb R)$ is a vector space.

How can we know that all properties of a vector space are met?

Comment: hint: they're not

Comment: @amakelov, Could you expand your answer?

Comment: What happens to a $z \in \mathbb{C}$ if you multiply it by a negative number? Then maybe add another complex number to it?